# Get the previous value on a keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application where I want to do something when the user taps backspace (key code 8) and the value is empty. But when I try it with `keyup` event, I get the value after the key has been pressed and that's not what I want.
Also I don't wanna use `keydown` because I wanna get the current value for something else.

Basically, the GOTCHA does fire when there's no value and backspace is pressed, but it alse fires when there's a character that was just removed.

What I want is, only log GOTCHA when the previous value of the input is empty.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('input').on('keyup', e => {
    // this is the condition for now, it need to be edited
    const condition = !$(e.target).val().length && e.keyCode === 8;
    if (condition) {
      console.log('GOTCHA'); // this fires before it should be fired
    }
    console.log($(e.target).val().length + ', ' + e.keyCode);
  });
  $('input').on('keydown', e => {
    console.log($(e.target).val().length + ', ' + e.keyCode);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<span></span>
```

This is a fiddle to give you an idea of what I want to achieve
https://jsfiddle.net/0z4cyj2e/1/

Thanks for looking into this :)

Comment: just calculate the condition in the keydown? [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/0z4cyj2e/3/)

Comment: `it alse fires when there's a character that was just removed.` I cannot replicate that behaviour. The code in your fiddle works as you require - it only shows `GOTCHA` when you attempt to delete with an empty field. Here's your same logic tidied up so it's clearer: https://jsfiddle.net/0z4cyj2e/2/

Comment: Also note that you should post all relevant code in the question. People shouldn't have to leave SO to understand what you're asking. I've edited the question for you to include the snippet.

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano I know it works the way I want it with keydown, but I need the current value in another part of that callback, so I can't use it. Thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I actually just tested it and it doesn't work the way I want it. when you press backspace and there's one character in the input, it fire GOTCHA

Comment: i'd like to repeat myself, you can calculate the condition in the `keydown`, then show the message in the `keyup`. ([here the sample](https://jsfiddle.net/0z4cyj2e/3/)). BUT, is really this what you need?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In that case, use `keydown`, not `keyup`: https://jsfiddle.net/0z4cyj2e/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might save the previous value in `data` props of the input on `keydown`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('input').on('keyup', e => {
    // this is the condition for now, it need to be edited
    const condition = !$(e.target).data('previousValue').length && e.keyCode === 8;
    if (condition) {
      console.log('GOTCHA'); // this fires before it should be fired
    }
    console.log($(e.target).val().length + ', ' + e.keyCode);
  });
  $('input').on('keydown', e => {
    console.log($(e.target).val().length + ', ' + e.keyCode);
    $(e.target).data('previousValue', $(e.target).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<span></span>
```

Comment: I ended up dividing the callback into two, Thanks :)